# Uibuttons keep freezing when clicked

Tags: ios, xcode, uibutton

Im trying to gather the information on how many time the button is clicked and it freezes when clicked.  This is just after an animation has occurred.

```
- (IBAction)btnGreen:(id)sender {
    greenCount++;
    NSLog(@"%i",greenCount);
}

- (IBAction)btnRed:(id)sender {
    redCount++;
}
- (IBAction)btnBlue:(id)sender {
    blueCount++;
}

- (IBAction)btnYellow:(id)sender {
    yellowCount++;
}
```

Comment: I guess you have to manually deselect your button.

Comment: I think more code needed to understand the issue. Please post some code where you create the buttons and assign selectors to them.

Comment: i created them in a storyboard